# Android Kotlin Volley slow request duplicates get request

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I use the Volley framework to make GET requests to my Flask API. This is the syntax I use to do that:

```
val jsonObjectRequest =
                JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,  url, null, { response ->
                    val spiScanApiResponse = response["success"] as String

                    if (spiScanApiResponse == "true") {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "SCANS SENT WITH SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "SCANS WERE NOT SENT!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        )
                            .show()                            
                    }
                },
                    {

                    }
                )
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

I am getting this "Volley: [111] NetworkUtility.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://myUrl 0xbeaaf2f6 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=6596], [size=114], [rc=200], [retryCount=1]" and this is duplicating the GET request and sends twice the data to my database.

From what I read it's a RetryPolicy / Timeout issue, but I can't find anything to help using Kotlin, all the possible answers I get are in Java and I can't find anything on Google about Kotlin Version of RetryPolicy or Timeout.

Is there a way to make this work using Volley? I wouldn't want to switch all my requests to another framework as this is the only request that does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and here it is how, in Kotlin:

to no more have duplicated requests I had to set the `jsonObjectRequest.retryPolicy` before adding it to the queue like this:

```
jsonObjectRequest.retryPolicy = 
    DefaultRetryPolicy(
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    )
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

And that's it.
Now it works like a charm!
I hope this will help others too.